# Excel find next available date from list of day/time slots

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Within Excel, say I have a list of available days and times (2 separate columns) which are available every week:

```
DAY         TIME
Monday      5:00 PM
Tuesday     4:00 PM
Wednesday   11:00 AM
Thursday    4:00 PM
Friday      11:00 AM
Friday      12:00 PM
```

This list is variable and can be changed at any time, so the solution needs to be a formula that can re-calc based on the available list changing.

Then I have a column of possible "start" dates/times:

```
START TIME
3/12/19 3:00 PM (Tuesday)
3/12/19 4:00 PM (Tuesday)
3/15/19 2:00 PM (Friday)
```

Is there a way I can calculate the next 3 available days/times in 3 separate columns next to the start date as an actual date that follows the initial start date?  If the available day is the same day of the week as the start date, it needs to check if the time is before the available time.  If it is, then it can be later that same day...if the start time is after the available time, then it has to be a week later.

The calculated times can be the same as a previous row, so the formulas don't need to take into account any sort of double-booking.  The same date/time in 2 separate rows would result in the same 3 next available dates/times.

So in the example above, it would result in:

```
START TIME          Next Available Date 1    Next Available Date 2    Next Available Date 3
3/12/19 3:00 PM     3/12/19 4:00 PM          3/13/19 11:00 AM         3/14/19 4:00 PM          
3/12/19 4:01 PM     3/13/19 11:00 AM         3/14/19 4:00 PM          3/15/19 11:00 AM 
3/15/19 2:00 PM     3/18/19 5:00 PM          3/19/19 4:00 PM          3/20/19 11:00 AM
```

I have been trying with array formulas, but can't get it to work for all cases.  The solution needs to be formula-based and without use of VBA or UDFs.

Comment: I think you are asking the wrong question. IMHO you need a list calculated from NOW() based on the list of available dates, basically a conversion of your weekday based list to a date based list which excludes anything that is in the past and extends at least 7 days into the future. It's in this list you can then find 3 future dates without the need to either convert dates to weekdays or exclude past dates. Obviously, that task can only be tackled once you have a suitable list to refer to.

Comment: I don't think Now() plays into it as it has to determine the next dates from the listed start date.  That is the basis of future vs. past.  If the start date was 3 years ago, it still should calculate the next 3 dates after that.  And it shouldn't matter whether Now() changes (i.e., I open it up today vs. tomorrow).

Comment: This is useful to know. The point is to avoid the rule, "if the available day is the same day as the start date it needs to check the time". This will double or treble the size of the formula and should be excluded by having not a start date but a start time, and to have no unsuitable date included in the list, meaning, the list must be constructed to include only suitable times.

Answer (score 0):

This could go down like a lead balloon and it may be over engineered but if you're looking for a VBA solution, this should work for you.

Add the below code into a new module within your VBA editor ...

```
Public Function CalculateNextAvailableDay(ByVal rngAvailableDays As Range, ByVal dtDate As Date, ByVal lngAvailableDayIndex As Long) As Date
    Dim strThisDay As String, tmThisTime As Variant, i As Long, intAvailableDay As Integer, lngRow As Long, dtNextDate As Date, arrNextAvailableDates() As Variant
    Dim lngArrayIndex As Long, intNextDateDay As Integer, lngMaxSecondsDiff As Long, lngSecondsDiff As Long, intDateOffset As Integer
    Dim lngIndexToRemove As Long, x As Long, bBeenThrough As Boolean

    Application.Volatile

    ' First, build up the range of next available DATES, not DAYS.
    For lngRow = 1 To rngAvailableDays.Rows.Count
        strThisDay = UCase(Trim(rngAvailableDays.Cells(lngRow, 1)))

        tmThisTime = TimeValue(rngAvailableDays.Cells(lngRow, 2).Text)

        Select Case strThisDay
            Case "SUNDAY"
                intAvailableDay = 1
            Case "MONDAY"
                intAvailableDay = 2
            Case "TUESDAY"
                intAvailableDay = 3
            Case "WEDNESDAY"
                intAvailableDay = 4
            Case "THURSDAY"
                intAvailableDay = 5
            Case "FRIDAY"
                intAvailableDay = 6
            Case "SATURDAY"
                intAvailableDay = 7
        End Select

        dtNextDate = DateValue(Split(CStr(dtDate))(0)) + tmThisTime
        intDateOffset = 0

        Do While 1 = 1
            dtNextDate = DateAdd("d", intDateOffset, dtNextDate)
            intNextDateDay = Weekday(dtNextDate)

            intDateOffset = 1

            If intNextDateDay = intAvailableDay And dtNextDate >= dtDate Then
                ' This date counts, add it to the list of available next dates.
                ReDim Preserve arrNextAvailableDates(lngArrayIndex)
                arrNextAvailableDates(lngArrayIndex) = dtNextDate

                lngArrayIndex = lngArrayIndex + 1

                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    Next

    ' Now find the next available date.
    For x = 1 To lngAvailableDayIndex
        lngMaxSecondsDiff = 0
        bBeenThrough = False

        ' We have all of the next available dates.
        For i = 0 To UBound(arrNextAvailableDates)
            If arrNextAvailableDates(i) <> "" Then
                lngSecondsDiff = Abs(DateDiff("s", arrNextAvailableDates(i), dtDate))

                If lngSecondsDiff < lngMaxSecondsDiff Or Not bBeenThrough Then
                    lngMaxSecondsDiff = lngSecondsDiff
                    lngIndexToRemove = i
                    bBeenThrough = True
                End If
            End If
        Next

        dtNextDate = arrNextAvailableDates(lngIndexToRemove)
        arrNextAvailableDates(lngIndexToRemove) = ""
    Next

    CalculateNextAvailableDay = dtNextDate
End Function
```

... and to use, define a named range called **rngAvailableDays** over the top (not including headers) of your first table.

With your matrix, change the headings for "Available Date 1" etc. to be just numbers, e.g. ...

- "Available Date 1", change to "1"
- "Available Date 2", change to "2"
- "Available Date 3", change to "3"

You can then custom format them to ... "Available Date" 0 ... so they display as they were before, but they need to be just numbers.

Once you've done that, add the following formula into the first cell of your "next available date" matrix ...

```
=CalculateNextAvailableDay(rngAvailableDays,$D2,E$1)
```

... replacing "$D2" with the first start date and "E$1" with the "Available Date 1" header field.

Now fill down and across and cross your fingers, it should work for you.

**BE SURE TO FORMAT DATES AS DATES AND TIMES AS TIMES!**

I hope that's all clear.

Let me know how you go.

Comment: Thanks, but I should have made it clearer that it needs to be an all-formula solution without VBA or UDFs.